# Creating Fragments for login

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing a login screen having fragments has shown in below image but i am not sure of how to do it in activity ,i had seen few tutorials like vogella and all but still i am not able to achieve the desired output.[image]

and the screen i developed is like 
[image]

the activity xml is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/username"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
        android:onClick="login"
        android:text="@string/Login" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="@string/attempts"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know how to get the similar screen ,i can add the image no issues but fragments not yet possible ,i am complete new to andriod,please help.

Thanks,

Comment: So, you're asking us to draw your UI...

Comment: y should i do that @Der Golem, i am just asking the way this is achieved has i am new,i dont require the code

Comment: Well, it just looks like a custom Dialog/DialogFragment, to me. Check the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

Comment: thanks @Der Golem ,i will have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffcbb9"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#ff9872"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_day"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="username" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_day"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="login"
            android:text="Login" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ,your coding is working perfectly,i want to display logo in the top mid center but its getting displayed in the mid center

Comment: <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         />

Comment: just remove android:layout_marginTop="100dp"

Comment: if i remove that it takes the mid username and password design to top along with logo

Comment: i am adding imageview in first linear layout

Comment: yes it works finally my login design is design thanks.

Comment: please see the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858216/list-of-item-display-with-scroll

Comment: please check out this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875045/right-corner-menu-option

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can create two fragments with their respective layouts (a logged out and a logged in fragment). Both fragments are going to be in MainActivity and in OnCreate you must hide the logged in fragment and show the logged out fragment with fragment transactions.

This is the main layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.LoggedOutFragment"
        android:id="@+id/loggedOutFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_logged_out"/>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.LoggedInFragment"
        android:id="@+id/loggedInFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_logged_in"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Each fragment is going to have it's respective layout. This is the OnCreate Method in MainActivity

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
loggedInFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.loggedOutFragment);
loggedOutFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.loggedInFragment);

FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
transaction.hide(loggedInFragment);
transaction.show(loggedOutFragment);        
transaction.commit();
```

(You can see more of this here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

After hiding the logged in fragment, you create an OnClick Listener for the login button and compare the user and password values with some values you have stored or hard coded strings, if they match, you hide the logged out fragment and show the logged in fragment (oposite process than before). When you log out you must do the oposite. Hope this helps and is exactly what you asked for.