# Right corner menu option

Tags: android

[image: image1]
I am not able to set the background image for the title bar i can only set color ,let me know what i have to change in the below code.
I want an exact below image 1 replica,the output i am getting is shown in figure 2

[image: image 2]

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ShowRoom"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and my activity java file

```
public class ItemActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.itemlist);

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.item);
    }
}
```

and styles.xml

```
<style name="TitleBarTheme" parent="android:Theme">
            <item name="android:windowTitleSize">35dip</item>
            <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBarBG</item>
        </style>
```

Comment: @Mike Guys please remove onhold tag,i have edited my question

Comment: you mean You need to place an custom icon in ActionBar and Some texts under ActionBar?

Comment: would you draw what you want on a paper or something else and post it's picture in question so that I can help you properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for text Alignment,this should do it

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/left_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="ShowRoom" />
```

As for ActionBar, first Add an xml Custom layout to your layout folder like this:
**custom_actionbar_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in your activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.Layout.xyz);
    initUI();
}
private void initUI(){
    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar_layout);
}
```

As for that Menu Icon on right side of ActionBar, it's called MenuItem, try inflating Menu using "onCreateOptionsMenu" and setting showAsAction in it's xml to whatever you wish for, for example add an xml to res/menu folder like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/ContctUs"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|withText"
    android:title="@string/ContactUs"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_info"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/skin1"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|withText"
    android:title="@string/skin1"
    android:visible="false"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"/>
```

And in your Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      if (item.getItemId() == R.id.ContctUs) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,ContactUs.class));
      return(true);
      }else if(...){...}
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

Hope this works.
Note:
this method is used on Pre-L design, If you want to target android-L, consider using Toolbar.(support.v7.widget.Toolbar)

Comment: i need to set a background image for the whole title has shown in the image and make the last image clickable

Comment: I want the layout has shown in my main question,a image text and clickable image these items are in title bar and just below title bar i have to display few text has shown

Comment: Okay, if what you have shown in picture is what you want, you should consider using Toolbar in your app, that's android design spec for handling menu as You know it. I'll give you some code soon

Comment: i need to customise this

Comment: Are you targeting android 5x or android 4x ?

Comment: 4x version but i need a common custimization

Comment: @sarah btw from now on you can notify me and ask your questions via my mail(erfan.molaei@gmail.com) I guess it's better :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68645/discussion-between-sarah-and-erfan-mowlaei).

Comment: In xml layout of actionbar set background of linear layout to whatever you want and that's it

Comment: I had tried using andriod:src in my layout but its not working,can you please edit in my layout and see if its working for you

Comment: use android:background to give Layouts a background and only use android:src for ImageViews.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020861/displaying-data-in-listview please see this