# Displaying data in listview

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to design a listview wherein i have to display two to three data for rows of each column,but i am not able to do so,i am getting the data has in image a but i want to display has in image b,i can display only single data in each row of each column.For example the column states to display the value of item number and style number ,i am able to display only item number but not style number.

[image]

```
**DataDisplay xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
**Listview xml** 
  <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="#00000000"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp"
           />
</LinearLayout>
```

**adapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    String [] result;
    String [] result1;
    String [] result2;
    String [] result3;
    String [] result4;
    Context context;
    int [] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(ItemActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList,String[] prgmNameList1,String[] prgmNameList2,String[] prgmNameList3,String[] prgmNameList4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        result1=prgmNameList1;
        result2=prgmNameList2;
        result3=prgmNameList3;
        result4=prgmNameList4;

        context=mainActivity;

        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        TextView tv1;
        TextView tv2;
        TextView tv3;
        TextView tv4;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null);
        holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.tv1=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.tv2=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        holder.tv3=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        holder.tv4=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        holder.tv1.setText(result1[position]);
        holder.tv2.setText(result2[position]);
        holder.tv3.setText(result3[position]);
        holder.tv4.setText(result4[position]);
        rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F1F1FF"));

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

**called from activity**

```
 public static String [] prgmNameList={"123456","456665","123445","5675343"};
    public static String [] prgmNameList1={"15.56","15.562","15.67","15.455"};
    public static String [] prgmNameList2={"9999","9999","9999","9999"};
    public static String [] prgmNameList3={"99%","99%","99%","99%"};
    public static String [] prgmNameList4={"9999","9999","9999","9999"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.itemlist);

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.item);
        context=this;

        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, prgmNameList,prgmNameList1,prgmNameList2,prgmNameList3,prgmNameList4));
    }
```

Comment: how you showing data in textview? in adapter?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=9) tutorial.

Comment: @DhavalGondaliya yes

Comment: If your are using custom lisview, show your  adapter code.

Comment: @DhavalGondaliya Please see the edited and added classes

Comment: you need to make new xml for custom listview with one data in a row. Please make 2 textview for each cell.

Comment: can you show an example

Comment: In your current xml replace each textview with group of textview in linearlayout with vertical orientation. thats it.

Comment: i tried but its hiding the other column data and showing the grouped text in linerlayout

Comment: @DhavalGondaliya can you please if its working for you,taking my class

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom layout for your row item where you can place two textviews one below the other to show your data as you want. Then override the `getView()` method of your adapter and inflate this custom layout and populate it with data from an array / list.

See the `getView()` method in the link mentioned in giacavicchioli's answer.

Comment: i have tried this but its not working out ,its hiding other columns,can you please edit in my example above and show.

Comment: See the implementation in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626825/android-customize-list-view-table-view-in-adapter
Here, the custom layout for the row item has a table that is populated in adapter's getView() method

Comment: I am not using tablelayout

Comment: Give all your textboxes in the horizontal LinearLayout a width of 0dp and a weight of 1. See if this makes other columns appear in view. 
FYI, you need to modify the custom layout for the row item to add another horizontal LinearLayout below the first one to show style# etc.

Answer (score 0):

As [user87049](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3060087/user87049) has said this will solve your problem sarah:

```
**DataDisplay xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

tell me if this this is not what you want :)
Ah and since I'm a bit busy these days and I may not come to this account on stackoverflow, please send me email to get my attention please [erfan.molaei@gmail.com]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did. Make a xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FF00" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#0000FF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FF00" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#0000FF" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FF00" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#0000FF" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FF00" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#0000FF" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is your custom `listview` xml file. Now in getView method setText to this all textview as you did for your xml file.

Check out below screen:

[image: Custom_listview_row]